How to reset matplotlib backend for 3D plot?
I was trying to plot an interactive 3D scatterplot on Matplotlib in a Jupyter Notebook where I also have Seaborn imported (will be important for the question), and I did this:
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib widget

sns.set(style = "darkgrid")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

x = dc['Email_Clicks']
y = dc['App_Clicks']
z = dc['SM_Score']

ax.set_xlabel("Email")
ax.set_ylabel("App")
ax.set_zlabel("SM")

ax.scatter(x, y, z)

plt.show()

It worked and generated my interactive 3D plot:
Interactive 3D scatterplot
But after I import Axes3D and set %matplotlib widget as a backend, all the other plots from Seaborn doesn't run anymore, for example:
Error description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 1
----> 1 sns.scatterplot(data = dc, x = 'Email_Clicks', y= 'App_Clicks')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py:761, in scatterplot(data, x, y, hue, size, style, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, style_order, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    758 color = kwargs.pop("color", None)
    759 kwargs["color"] = _default_color(ax.scatter, hue, color, kwargs)
--> 761 p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    763 return ax

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py:573, in _ScatterPlotter.plot(self, ax, kws)
    570     kws.setdefault("edgecolor", "w")
    572 # Draw the scatter plot
--> 573 points = ax.scatter(x=x, y=y, **kws)
    575 # Apply the mapping from semantic variables to artist attributes
    577 if "hue" in self.variables:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1446, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1443 @functools.wraps(func)
   1444 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1445     if data is None:
-> 1446         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1449     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1450                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

TypeError: Axes3D.scatter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'xs' and 'ys'

It only happens after I pass through the cell where I import Axes3D and set %matplotlib widget. What can it be?
I tried to reset the backend to inline after running the plot, and also deleting the import of Axes 3D, with something like
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib widget

sns.set(style = "darkgrid")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

x = dc['Email_Clicks']
y = dc['App_Clicks']
z = dc['SM_Score']

ax.set_xlabel("Email")
ax.set_ylabel("App")
ax.set_zlabel("SM")

ax.scatter(x, y, z)

plt.show()

%matplotlib inline
del Axes3D

but it keeps happening, it looks like one of those changes (importing Axes3D or changing the backend) are changing more things than I expected.

Do you want to use two different backends in the same jupyter cell? You do need to create a new figure with a non-3d ax when you want to plot via seaborn. The error you get, is that you are trying to plot a 2D plot onto a 3D ax.  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D should not make a difference.  fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') does make a difference, but only until you select or create a different ax.
